# grub doesn't work after dual booting win 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Just installed win8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 lts But the grub doesn't show at all When booting.... Also Nothing happens When I press  during the booting process. It just loads the Ubuntu as default

Comment: Have you tried holding down shift during boot? I believe this is how the GRUB menu is revealed if it's hiding.

Comment: Just tried this and the grub doesn't give the option to load the windows partition

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu last? Did you manually partition, or did you let the installer install Ubuntu side by side with Windows?

Comment: Installed Ubuntu last; used windows to allocate 500gb for the Ubuntu installation